# Call a JavaScript function using variables for both the service and the function name

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my Angular Controller, I have a need to call a function using variables. The problem is that both service and the function names are dynamically defined, so they both will be variables. I am using the Angular $injector to get the Angular service name without problem. However, the function call does not work:

```
// serviceTypeName and functionTypeName are from the view
// vm.initiate() is invoked by ng-click
//
// $injector is injected to the controller


vm.initiate = function(serviceTypeName, functionTypeName) {
  // e.g., if serviceTypeName is 'abcService' and the functionTypeName is 'foo'
  // then abcService.foo() is what I hope to get.
  // abcService.foo() is defined in the abcService.

  var resourceService = $injector.get(serviceTypeName);

  // the following works:
  var data = resourceService.foo();


  // the following statements do not work 
  var result = resourceService.functionTypeName(); // does not work
  var result1 = resourceService.eval(functionTypeName)(); // does not work either
}
```

Is it possible to do so using AngularJS 1.5.x? If so, can someone help me to resole this issue?

Comment: resourceService[functionTypeName]();

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try this (in browser console):

```
var p = { myMethod: function(){console.log('called');}, myProp: 'asd'  }
```

Now, if you write `p['myMethod']()`, you would see the function getting called. In the same manner, when you do `resourceService[functionTypeName]()`, your function should get called.

```
var result = resourceService[functionTypeName](); //should work
```

Comment: @redixint - you can mark it as answer if this works for you. other users will know that the question has got the solution